# Why would Matlab's `rand(1,1e9)` make 64-bit Windows 7 unresponsive?

Tags: matlab

When I start a new Matlab session, the `rand(1,1e9);` command causes my 64-bit Windows 7 to become unresponsive.  That means once every few minutes, it might respond to a mouse click or some such from a few minutes back, but otherwise, I can't even flip between apps, can't invoke the task manager, and if the task manager was running before the `rand(1,1e9);` command, can't even scroll to Matlab on the Processes tab.  I don't get an out-of-memory message.  Clicking on Matlab's "X" icon to close the app doesn't do anything.  Ctrl-C doesn't do anything, and neither does Break in unison with any 1-, 2-, and 3-key combination of Shift, Ctrl, and Alt.

It might be informative to know that `rand(1,1e8);` (10x fewer doubles) doesn't cause these problems and finishes in (relatively) no time at all.

The memory info from the `memory` command is:

```
>> memory
Maximum possible array:     12782 MB (1.340e+10 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:     12782 MB (1.340e+10 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:       674 MB (7.068e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):      8070 MB (8.462e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

On the few occasions in which I can kill Matlab, the OS remains hardly responsive as described above, even when the task manager shows the memory usage go from 7.9GB to nearly zero.

How can Matlab's `rand(1,1e9);` cause this persistent OS irresponsiveness?  Assuming the problem is memory related, how can I ensure that Matlab plays nicely with the OS (and/or vice-versa) when these limits are being bumped up against?

Please note that this is not a question about how to avoid bumping against the memory limits, as I know I can code around them. It's about how to avoid the loss of control when the limits are bumped up against so that I can decide whether I want to interrupt or kill the operation and/or app.  For example, [Matlab's Memory Allocation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-allocation.html?refresh=true) shows that 1e9 doubles takes 8e9 bytes, so together with other memory requirements, I'm probably bumping up against the real and swap memory shown above.  No matter if I get an error, or the command simply takes much, much longer, I would still want Matlab to respond to keyboard requests to break. I would also want the rest of the OS to be responsive, including the use of the task manager to kill Matlab in the event that it doesn't respond to a break request.

Comment: It's probably not only about memory usage. Generating 1 billion random numbers takes some computation time.

Comment: Have you read [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html) and tried anything?

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps...but 100 million random doubles takes (comparatively) no time at all.  Something is hanging the machine, seemingly indefinitely. It leaves the OS in a bad state, even after Matlab is killed (when I am able to do so).

Comment: @horchler: Thank you for the link. I read it quickly, and it deserves a more detailed read.  Here is what `memory` reports.  Max possible array: 12782 MB; Mem available for all arrays: 12782 MB; Mem used by MATLAB: 674 MB (new session); Physical Memory (RAM): 8070 MB. However, I'm wondering if the page addresses my problem. (cont'd)

Comment: I don't get an out of memory error, and I don't necessarily want *more* swap memory. I thought that the problem was that virtual memory wasn't being used, so Matlab was hanging. I was hoping to enable virtual memory so that it wouldn't hang; if it remains responsive, I can *choose* whether to wait for it to churn through its operations or whether to interupt, cancel, kill, whatever. (cont'd)

Comment: Right now, everything, including task manager, is irresponsive with the rare exception, i.e., it might respond to a mouse click from minutes back. For the majority of the time, I can't even scroll to the Matlab process to see how much memory it's using. On the rare occassions in which I can, killig Matlab still doesn't bring the OS back to its responsive self. (cont'd)

Comment: I can, of course, take steps to reduce the memory requirements of operations, but I am running up against my problem in quick-and-dirty cobbling of commands. I'm trying to avoid the loss of control when that kind of hacking bumps up against memory constraints (if that's indeed the cause -- not likely to be anything else). I can then decide whether to make it less quick-and-dirty with more elaborate coding.

Comment: I get the same problem when trying to do `rand(1, 4e9)`. I find something really interesting. The final value can be stored in memory (about 20 gb). However, while generating the value the memory used by matlab spikes to over 30 gb! I think this is the cause of the unresponsiveness.

Comment: OK, so lots of memory is needed for the pseudorandom generation.  I'm pleasantly surprised that the task manager was responsive enough to show you the spike in memory. Are you confident enough about this result to post it as the answer? P.S. On my 64-bit Windows 7, the problem leaves the OS irresponsive even when I am able to kill Matlab.  Weird.